# Unable to use Joins in Sys RefCursor in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, sys-refcursor

I want to pass sys_refcursor as an argument to a procedure in PL/SQL.
I have used the following codes to create a procedure

```
create or replace procedure reffunmani(
  cname varchar2,
  mysys out sys_refcursor) 
is
begin   
  open mysys for
    select /*c.ins_id,c.cname, c.start_date,*/i.ins_id,i.ins_name
      from course c,institution i where c.ins_id=i.ins_id 
     order by c.start_date;
end;
/
show errors;
```

and i have called the same procedure i an anonymous block

```
declare
  mysys sys_refcursor;
  rec institution%rowtype; 
begin
  reffunmani('MCA',mysys);
  loop
    fetch mysys into rec;
    exit when mysys%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.ins_id||'    '||rec.ins_name);
  end loop;
  close mysys;
end;
/
```

When I execute my anonymous block, I get an error

```
ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match 
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

Note that the `institution` table has 5 columns.

Comment: `mysys` is a local variable so you wouldn't prefix it with a colon (which whatever front end tool you are using probably interprets as a bind variable).  Just `reffunmani('MCA',mysys);`

Comment: yes i tried but no use getting the same error msg

Comment: What is the full error stack including the error number when you remove the colon?  Does your `institution` table really only have the two columns?

Comment: no my institution table has five columns and course table has 5 columns..

Comment: ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match
ORA-06512: at line 7

Comment: this is the error i ma getting when i remove colon

Comment: Your cursor contains two columns.  Your local variable `rec` is of type `institution%rowtype`.  You can only fetch data from the cursor into this record if the cursor was returning all the columns from the `institution` table.  You could declare a local record type that has two fields and fetch the data into that in your anonymous block.

Comment: i have used all the column names in my sql statement i works perfectly as u said but if i want to display records from both institution and course table what should i do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the data from the cursor into a local variable `rec`.  That record is defined to be of type `institution%rowtype`.  That would work if and only if the cursor actually returned all the columns from the `institution` table (in the same order as they are defined in the table).  Since that is not the case here, you have a couple of options.

First, you can simply define a few scalar variables and fetch the data into those

```
declare
  mysys sys_refcursor;
  l_ins_id   institution.ins_id%type;
  l_ins_name institution.ins_name%type;
begin
  reffunmani('MCA',mysys);
  loop
    fetch mysys into l_ins_id, l_ins_name;
    exit when mysys%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_ins_id||'    '||l_ins_name);
  end loop;
  close mysys;
end;
/
```

Alternately, you can declare a local record type that has two fields and fetch data into that

```
declare
  mysys sys_refcursor;

  -- I'm guessing at your data types here
  type typ_my_rec is record (
    ins_id    integer,
    ins_name  varchar2(100)
  );
  rec typ_my_rec; 
begin
  reffunmani('MCA',mysys);
  loop
    fetch mysys into rec;
    exit when mysys%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.ins_id||'    '||rec.ins_name);
  end loop;
  close mysys;
end;
/
```